# population decline by yearly factor decrease

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, word-problem

Trying to help my daughter with a word problem.  Here's the question:

Every year the population of Springfield decreases by a factor of 1/6.  If the population of Springfield on Jan 1, 1980 was 3,521, what was the approximate population on Jan. 1, 2000?

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

This is a [geometric sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression), after $n$ years the population is $3521\cdot\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^n$.